# Inequality involving a selfadjoint endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Let  $V$ be an inner product space finitely generated over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\alpha$ be a positive-definite endomorphism of V. Show:

$$
\langle (\alpha+\alpha^{-1})v,v\rangle \geq 2 \langle v,v \rangle
$$

My attempt at a solution has been this so far: Since $\alpha$ is a self adjoint endomorphism over a finite vector space, it is diagonalizable. if $\{c_1,c_2,...,c_n\}$ are the eigenvalues of $\alpha$ in increasing order, then
$$
\langle (\alpha+\alpha^{-1})v,v\rangle = \langle \alpha(v),v \rangle+ \langle \alpha^{-1}(v),v\rangle \geq c_1 \langle v,v \rangle+\frac{1}{c_n} \langle v,v \rangle = \left(c_1+\frac{1}{c_n}\right) \langle v,v \rangle
$$
and this is as far as I've gotten. I don't see any conditions that will allow us to find bounds for the eigenvalues. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\alpha$ commutes with its inverse, so they have the same eigenvectors, which are also the eigenvectors of their sum. So you know the eigenvalues of their sum.

Comment: (This would be clear if you had looked at examples. As a general principle, if you can't see how to prove something then try to disprove it instead. Sometimes there will actually be a mistake and the statement will be wrong; other times you'll run into an obstruction which will give you an idea for the proof.)

Comment: I’ve used that fact in what I’ve written above. They have the same eigenvectors but the eigenvalues are reciprocals.

Comment: @mphy Let $v$ be an eigen-vector with eigen-value $c$. Can you prove the inequality for this specific $v$? Also, if the inequality is true for $v_1$ and $v_2$, then can you show that it also holds for $v_1+v_2$?

Comment: @mphy: once you break up into considering $c_1$ and $c_n$ separately you’re throwing away the information that they’re simultaneously diagonalizable. With simultaneity you can write down a better bound, involving the minimal value of $c_i + \frac{1}{c_i}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That makes more sense, I will give that a shot. Thank you